# ssh-agent command doesn't create env variables as stated in a man page on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, ssh-agent

When I run `ssh-agent` it does output to the console:

```
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-6xVL11wer5lW/agent.311122; export SSH_AUTH_SOCK;
SSH_AGENT_PID=311122; export SSH_AGENT_PID;
echo Agent pid 311122;
```

However no environmental variables are seen when run `env`. What is the problem? It does work with:

```
eval `ssh-agent` && ssh-add
```

But I wish to understand why cannot I simply use `ssh-agent`

UPD: On local machine I also have added file `/home/user/.ssh/config` to replace the need of using ssh-add:

```
AddKeysToAgent yes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the `eval` statement is **mandatory** to create those variables.

The command itself just print the variables/values, but are not declaring anything alone. That's the point using `eval`

Comment: but `eval` cannot be used inside, for example Python script, like os.execvp()

Comment: This is not in your question.

Comment: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=ssh-agent+with+python&t=ffab&ia=web